# How to make Registration / authorization With Radiant cms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, radiant

I need Regestration page . with field :Email Username and Password. and then User can login  on login page. How to make this Authorization with Radiant cms

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at radiant-reader-extension. There also exist several other extensions (forum, reader groups, ...) building upon that.

Seeing that you need a 'front end' User class, it seems your project is tilting towards a web app (as opposed to a web site). If the project leans too much in that direction, you may want to nót use Radiant for it due to the restrictions that come with it (brings it's own Rails (2.3), must be extended through extensions, ...).